# How to reorder struct columns?

Tags: data-structures, coldfusion

I'm trying to display my results from a CFQuery in a specific order. The order is to be maintained in the database so that it can be manipulated, and there are an unknown number of columns per table. The final row in the table is "ColumnOrder": each column has a number to specify it's sort order, 0 means "don't display". I'm trying to sort by looping say, "y" from 1 to maxCols:

0) do y = 1 to maxCols

1) in the ***sortColumn*** result set, use y to lookup the corresponding KEY

2) in the ***products*** result set, find the value from the corresponding KEY

3) insert said value into tempStruct[y]

4) loop.

I'm running into a wall trying to use structFindKey(). Here's my code:

```
<CFQUERY name="qParts" datasource="Pascal">         
    SELECT * FROM Turbos WHERE PartNumber LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="30" value="%#mfr#%"> ORDER BY #sort# ASC 
</CFQUERY>
<cfquery name="qPartsOrder" datasource="Pascal">
    SELECT * FROM Turbos WHERE PartNumber = 'ColumnOrder'
</cfquery>

<cfset tempStruct=structnew()>
        <cfloop index="columnOrder2" from="1" to="#ListLen(qPartsOrder.ColumnList, ',')#">
            <cfdump var="#StructFindKey(qPartsOrder, columnOrder2)#">
            <cfset tempStruct[columnOrder2] = StructFindKey(#qPartsOrder#, "#columnOrder2#")>
            <cfset currentCol = "#ListGetAt(qParts.columnList, columnOrder2, ',')#">
            <cfoutput>#qParts[currentCol][qParts.currentrow]# <br/></cfoutput>
        </cfloop>
<cfdump var="#tempstruct#">
```

The line

```
<cfdump var="#StructFindKey(qPartsOrder, columnOrder2)#">
```

is throwing a BLANK!! error message, so I can't debug it and I'm stuck.

Any and all help would be appreciated (and YES I have to use **SELECT ***, this is a generic product display page for displaying ALL information in the database except a few which are denoted by a zero in the order column, remember?).

Comment: First, qPartsOrder is not a structure. It is a query object. Perhaps you meant to search qPartsOrder.columnList via list functions? Second, what do you mean "final row in the table is 'ColumnOrder'"?

Comment: "Second, what do you mean "final row in the table is 'ColumnOrder'"" Believe it or not, I think the table looks like `PartNumber,Name,Date,Mfr|1,Widget,1/1/2000,Acme|2,Foo,2/2/2000,Tyco|"ColumnOrder",1,3,2`

Comment: Umm.. that is what I was afraid of. I agree with @Jordan Reiter. There are far simpler, and better, ways to do this. So do you have control over the schema?

Comment: I used the wrong term, sorry. The final RECORD in the table contains the order information for each column, not the final row. I had a headache and couldn't think very clearly. I do have control over the schema, but I have mentioned that because of the nature of a product database, **there is NO way to manually query all columns, since there will be different tables for each category of product and my boss wants ONE page to display the details for each.**

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to get around the stupid alphabetizing CF does on queries .

Comment: You could always store the column information in another table. Then query it to build your SELECT list. Then it is configurable. Finally use your list or query metadata to obtain the original column order.

Comment: @Scott - Never mind. I see you have seen the light already ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand the problem you are trying to solve. The is exacerbated by a very unconventional way of setting up a database.

To begin with, if you are not lucky you may run into a documented error where using a `cfqueryparam` tag throws an error of `Value cannot be converted to requested type` although I don't know if this still happens with current versions of ColdFusion (8+).

In any case, you can always select *all* of the columns of the table manually even if you don't know how many of them will ultimately be used:

```
SELECT partNumber, secondColumn, thirdColumn, ... , nthColumn
FROM Turbos
```

This is generally preferable to just using `SELECT *` although it presents some problems if you are in the habit of frequently adding/removing columns to tables.

Unless you need to use a Struct for good reason, you should use an Array instead. Structs don't store ordering information while Arrays do. Here is one way to sort through the records in qParts:

```
<cfset RecordsArray=ArrayNew(2)>
<cfset ColumnIndex=StructNew()>
<cfloop list="#qPartsOrder.ColumnList#" index="order_column">
    <cfset ColumnIndex[order_column]=val(qPartsOrder[order_column][1])>
</cfloop>
<cfloop query="qParts">
    <cfloop list="#qPartsOrder.ColumnList#" index="order_column">
        <cfif val(ColumnIndex[order_column])>
            <cfset RecordsArray[ColumnIndex[order_column]][qParts.CurrentRow]=qParts[order_column][qParts.CurrentRow]>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

The result of this code will be a 2D array, with the first number referring to the column index and the second index pointing to the record row.

All in all, I think that unless you have zero control over how the database is structured, there is a better way to implement this, starting with how you've set up your database. It would really help to see some fake sample data as well as having a clearer idea of what you are trying to accomplish -- what will you do with these ordered fields once you have them, for example?

Comment: Jordan, there is no way I can manually query all columns, since there will be different tables for each category of product and my boss wants ONE page to display the details for each. Thanks for your code though, I'll see what I can do with it.

Comment: I'm confused. If you are writing `SELECT * FROM Turbos` then clearly you are referencing a specific table, and you should know the fields for that table. Is that not really what is happening?

Comment: You have a point. Here's my goal: I'm reconstructing a database for my company. We sell high-tech vacuum research equipment, and our current database schema will prohibit us from using a faceted search on our products. Our current database uses several fixed columns and stores the product description in a semicolon-delimited list inside one column. See http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/7793/relationships.jpg for relationships.

I'm partly being lazy because there are going to be 12 tables with up to sixty columns each and we may add or remove columns via the DB administration page we have.

Comment: My subgoal is to be able to display any information based on the column name and the column order. The information has to be presented in a specific order on the page to make sense, hence my reason for wanting an ordered struct (or array) to loop over. I do realize there are other ways to structure the database, so feel free to throw ideas at me. (but do hurry, I'm a bit of a newbie and my boss is getting impatient ;-) )

Comment: Hey, wait a minute! I can use a separate table to keep track of the all the columns and their order, just like we already have. DUH! Sorry for the confusion Jordan, I think I know what I need to do.

Answer (score -1):

Dun you try to use `StructSort` ?

Comment: qPartsOrder is not a structure. It is a query object.